# How to sort_by dates in csv using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, csv

[This my csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5aAG.png),I need to sort the rows according to the earliest date of States node.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
xmlfile = File.read("test3.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlfile)
all = []
doc.css('Firm').each_with_index do |firm,i|
 firstchild  = []
 secondchild =[]
firm.css('States').each do |rgltr_addr_node|
 if rgltr_addr_node.has_attribute?("RgltrCd")
  RgltrCd =rgltr_addr_node.attributes["RgltrCd"]&&rgltr_addr_node.attributes["RgltrCd"].value
 else 
 RgltrCd = "NA"
end
if rgltr_addr_node.has_attribute?("St")
  St = rgltr_addr_node.attributes["St"] && rgltr_addr_node.attributes["St"].value
else
St = "NA"
end
if rgltr_addr_node.has_attribute?("Dt")
  Dt = rgltr_addr_node.attributes["Dt"] && rgltr_addr_node.attributes["Dt"].value
else 
Dt ="NA"
end
firstchild[0] = RgltrCd 
firstchild[1] = St
firstchild[2] = Dt
end
firm.css('Filing').each do |filing_node|
if filing_node.has_attribute?("Dt")
  Dt = filing_node.attributes["Dt"] && filing_node.attributes["Dt"].value
else
Dt ="NA"
end
if filing_node.has_attribute?("FormVrsn")
  FormVrsn = filing_node.attributes["FormVrsn"] && filing_node.attributes["FormVrsn"].value
else 
FormVrsn ="NA"
end
  secondchild[0] = Dt 
  secondchild[1] = FormVrsn
 end
end
all << firstchild + secondchild 
end
```

I used the following looping for data to display in each row of csv:

```
CSV.open('new_test3_file.csv', 'wb' ) do |row|
    row << ['States', 'Filing']
    all.each do |data|
        row << data
    end
```

Can any one help me in sorting this by date?

Comment: What is `all` in above code? Array of string where date is provided  as a string ?

Comment: all is an array containing the combination of individual arrays

Comment: all = []  and i pushed my child arrays present in each nodes of States and Filing as follows: all << firstchild + secondchild

Comment: first code block indicates the  displayed output in csv

Comment: @ray, I updated my all[],it is having only two arrays.(firstchild and secondchild)

Comment: @TChaitanyaTatavolu Your question with data provided in not clear

Comment: @TChaitanyaTatavolu your question seems a bit inconsistent to me. Could you provide a filled example input array (i.e. `all`) and your expected output (along your code), please? It doesn't have to be your actual data, a simplified array would be just fine.

Comment: _"This my csv output"_ – not quite, that's a screenshot showing the CSV imported into a spreadsheet application (presumably). Please post the raw CSV data instead (it's a textual format, so you can put it in a code block).

Comment: @Stefan, I provided my .rb code

Answer (score 1):

Here, CSV is completely text data of string provided by comma.

`all` is array of data to be written on CSV file so I suggest you to sort data inside all as per your need first and then write on csv file.

```
all = [["Ut", "2009-01-12"], ["TY", "2003-12-21"], ["Rt", "2008-05-20"]]
```

Now sort it like below **if your date of state is 2nd value at inner array**

```
> all.sort! { |a,b| DateTime.parse(a[1]) <=>  DateTime.parse(b[1]) }
 # => [["TY", "2003-12-21"], ["Rt", "2008-05-20"], ["Ut", "2009-01-12"]]
```

Now you can write this sorted data on csv file.

Or you can use, (As @Stefan suggested in below comment)

```
all.sort_by! { |a| a[1] }
```

Comment: Or `all.sort_by!(&:last)`.

Comment: Please find my updated question once, I need to sort date with reference to particular node

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csv_rows = []
CSV.foreach('new_test3_file.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  csv_rows << row.to_h
end

csv_rows.sort_by{ |row| row['Dt'] }
```

Comment: Thank you,but it's not sorting.Actually i had  2 'Dt' coloumns under nodes.